# string to base64 and base64 to string in nestjs with export ability?

Tags: typescript, graphql, base64, nestjs

I create one file name `base.ts`. Here I have to write function for converting `string` to `base64` and vice versa.

But I have no idea how can I write in in `Nestjs`.

In expressjs I write it in this way-

```
module.exports.stringToBase64 = (data) => Buffer.from(data).toString('base64');
module.exports.base64ToString = (data) => Buffer.from(data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
```

I already copy it and paste it into `base.ts` file in Nest js project. And When I import it to another file then it stop my server or creashed my server.

Anyone can give me idea in this field.

Comment: this isn't related with nestjs nor with express, it's just nodejs (and commonjs). You have functions. Just use them like the usual

Comment: show us the error. You're problably importing things wrongly

Comment: also, in typescript, those lines will be `export const stringToBase64 = () => ...` (but again, it's typescript, not a nestjs thing)